# Is Dockerfile replacable with docker-compose.yaml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like to build and operate containers only with docker-compose. Is it possible to do it with using all features of the Dockerfile, but without using it?

IMHO not, but I'm not sure if it is true.
For example: are there any replacement of Dockerfile's RUN,ADD,COPY commands in the docker-compose.yaml? I can't find.

Comment: Mindig akad egy hülye... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no: the `Dockerfile` says how to build an image, and the `docker-compose.yml` says how to run it.  There are various combinations of things that it's impossible to do in one place or the other.

In some cases you can simulate things the `Dockerfile` might do with `docker-compose.yml` directives (you can use `volumes:` to mount content into a running container, which looks similar to `COPY`ing the content into an image) but they're not the same and you generally can't use exclusively one, unless you can describe your application using only prebuilt images.

I'd tend to recommend the Dockerfile `COPY` and `CMD` directives over trying to use only the `docker-compose.yml` equivalents.  Environment variables are often runtime configuration ("what is the host name of the database server?") and those it makes more sense to specify in the `docker-compose.yml` or other runtime configuration.